# Why will not my child record relate to my parent record in dataset saved to Access?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, dataset

So I have an MS Access DB with a parent table:

```
ID Autonumber
Description Text
```

A child table:

```
ID AutoNumber 
Description Text 
ParentID Number
```

I have created relationships:

```
Parent column: ID
Child column: ParentID
Enforce Ref Integrity, Cascade Update and Cascade Delete
```

I have dropped this into Visual Studio 2010, and the  wizard has created DataSets and Adapters.
I have modified the xsd to set the relationsship to `Both Relation and Foreign Key Constraint` and `Update/Delete` rules to `Cascade`.

So I try to add a parent record with an associated child record:

```
var taParent = new TestDataSetTableAdapters.ParentTableAdapter();
var taChild = new TestDataSetTableAdapters.ChildTableAdapter();
var ds = new TestDataSet();
taParent.Fill(ds.Parent);
taChild.Fill(ds.Child);

var rowParent = ds.Parent.NewParentRow();
rowParent.Description = DateTime.Now.ToString();
ds.Parent.AddParentRow(rowParent);

var rowChild = ds.Child.NewChildRow();
rowChild.ChildText = DateTime.Now.ToString();
ds.Child.AddChildRow(rowChild);

taParent.Update(ds);
var parentId = rowParent.ID;  // <-- This is still -1
// taParent.Fill(ds.Parent);  // <-- Doing this hoping to reload the parent record gives:  Cannot clear table Parent because ForeignKeyConstraint ParentChild enforces constraints and there are child rows in Child.

taChild.Update(ds.Child);
```

but the child records ParentID is null.

If I try to:

```
rowChild.SetParentRow(rowParent);
```

I'll get
`You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'Parent'.`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that after `taParent.Update(ds)` your `rowParent` actually has been updated and includes the proper `ID` from the database?

- If it does, have you tried to set `rowChild.SetParentRow(rowParent)` before you save the Child `taChild.Update(ds.Child)`?
- If your `rowParent` doesn't include a valid ID after `taParent.Update(ds)`, have you tried to reload it from the database before assigning it to the child?

It looks like the issue is probably related to the fact that auto-increment IDs cannot be known before the data has been saved to the database, and then reloaded from it so you can assign that value to other records.

Comment: Thanks, question updated with my attempts. The parent ID is never propagated back to the dataset. Reloading it fails.